# BackboneJS Get specific item from Model of Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to get the title of each model and after that split the title into artist + title.

The data is JSON delivered by https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/beta/uploads?alt=jsonc&v=2&max-results=48&orderby=published

My collection looks like this:

```
videoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function() {
        return 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/beta/uploads?alt=jsonc&v=2&max-results=48&orderby=published';
    },
    parse: function(res) {
        return res.data.items;    
    }           
}
```

First of all I tried:

```
var title = this.collection.each(function(item){
    item.get('title');
});
```

but that didnt work very well, so how can I get the title and split it up?

Comment: What do you mean "that didn't work very well"?

Comment: I mean that it didnt give me anything :-)